# Non-Coder Needs Help Replacing Named Anchors with Javascript or jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, anchor

I am in need of a coder. I admittedly am a Designer and almost completely dumb when it comes to coding. I apologize in advance for my obvious ignorance on the subject. I have tried to search for an answer to my question, but I don't understand code enough to be able to understand the answers given to similar questions.

I am trying to create a FAQ page in a tab on my Facebook business page using the Facebook Thunderpenny app. (I just have to paste in the code to get the tab to work.) I want to be able to click on a question link and have the link take me to the answer location on the same page. Under normal circumstances, I know I'd use a Named Anchor. Apparently Facebook tabs do not allow for the use of Named Anchors because they do not recognize the hashtag (#) used for this purpose since the page is contained within a tab frame.

I know there is a way to perform the same function as a Named Anchor by using using a Javascript or jQuery function; but I have no idea what the exact code would be, or where to place it in my current HTML code.

If what I have read on the subject is correct, then instead of adding a Named Anchor

```
<h2><a name="address"></a>What is your address and/or phone number? <br>
</h2>
```

I should give what would be the Named Anchor an ID

```
<h2 id="address">What is your address and/or phone number? <br>
</h2>
```

I can work with that, but what I want to know is what do I add to the code for the question at the top of the page

```
 <p>What is your address and/or phone number?</p>
```

to be able to click on it and make it jump to the answer on the same page found at the ID location

```
<h2 id="address">What is your address and/or phone number? <br>
</h2>
```

I have read about using Javascript functions such as scrollIntoView or scrollTo to replace using a Named Anchor, but I am unsure what to use, exactly what the code would be, and where to place the code. No matter how I search it online, no matter what I read, it still looks like Greek to me.

Any help is appreciated. Please use the lines of code, I provided above, in your examples/answers as this will make it easier for me to understand where the additional code specifically should be placed. I am open to suggestions; and the more simple the solution is, the better.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: You can go through this tutorial http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/

Comment: I really doubt this has anything to do with Facebook - what’s displayed inside the iframe is the content from the app’s domain, and Facebook does not modify that in any way. And using anchor links inside iframes is usually no problem either.

Comment: Yo Yo,
Thank you for the tutorial, but I don't understand code enough to understand what it means and where to put it.

CBroe,
I had the entire FAQ document set up with anchors, no errors in my code, worked great in my web preview and yet they did not work when I pasted the code into the app. Whatever the reason, Named Anchors/Anchor Tags do not work because one program or the other seems to be incapable of recognizing the hashtags necessary to use Named Anchors/Anchor Tags. I need another way to perform that function.